# Swift Generic Variables fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, generics, null

I'm trying to implement a simple generic method:

```
func findMax<T: Comparable>(numbers_array : [T]) -> ( min_tuple : T , max_tuple : T )
{
    var max_number : T?
    var min_number : T?

    for i in numbers_array
    {
        if(max_number < i)
        {
            max_number = i
        }
        if(min_number > i)
        {
            min_number = i
        }
    }
    return (min_number! , max_number!)
}
```

I am trying to access the method like this:

```
let result = findMax([3.4, 5, -7, -7.8])
```

But whenever I run this code I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I think thats because I haven't assigned a value to **var max_number : T?** and **var min_number : T?**

I can't assign a value to them because they are of generic type and I think the garbage value is messing with the logic of this function... I might be wrong but that is what I have been able to assess from my debugging session.

Thanks in advance, Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift is different to some other C-based languages in that it will not let you use an uninitialized variable that might contain garbage.  If you declare but don’t initialize a variable, then use it before it’s guaranteed to be initialized (based on the possible code paths), you get a compiler error.

But `var` optionals are implicitly initialized to `nil`.  So the problem here is your forced unwraps at the end (e.g. `min_number!`).  There are code paths that result in the `nil`s not getting reassigned to a real value, and then when you unwrap the `nil` with `!` you get an error.

The reason for this is this line here:

```
if(min_number > i)
```

There is a version of `>` that takes optionals.  If the two values are both non-`nil`, then it compares them.  But if one is `nil`, it is *always* less than a non-`nil` version.  So in your loop, you start with `min_number` as `nil`, so your `if` statement will never evaluate to true.

Here’s an alternative way of writing it that accounts for the possibility of an empty array:

```
func findMax<T: Comparable>(numbers_array : [T]) -> ( min_tuple : T , max_tuple : T )
{
    if let first_number = numbers_array.first {
        var min_number = first_number, max_number = first_number
        for i in dropFirst(numbers_array) {
            max_number = max(max_number, i)
            min_number = min(min_number, i)
        }
        return (min_number,max_number)
    }
    else {
        // the user has passed in an empty array... 
        // so there is no minimum, you must take some 
        // action like:
        fatalError("empty array passed")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of `fatalError` you could have your function return an optional, with `nil` if the sequence was empty.  In Swift 2.0 the `minElement` and `maxElement` methods switched from doing the former to doing the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Given that all considerations made by @AirspeedVelocity are correct, and his solution works great, if you are a fan of more compact but a little more cryptic code you can replace his `if` branch with the following code:

```
return dropFirst(numbers_array).reduce((numbers_array[0], numbers_array[0])) {
    ($1 < $0.0 ? $1 : $0.0, $1 > $0.1 ? $1 : $0.1)
}
```

which uses the `reduce` method to iteratively transform the array into a tuple of 2 elements.

The `dropFirst` discards the first element of the array, and the `reduce` method is applied to the resulting array.

The `reduce` method takes 2 parameters:

- the initial value, which in this case is a bi-dimensional tuple with both elements set to the array's first element
- a closure, applied to each element of the array, which returns a new tuple, determined by verifying whether the array element is less than/greater than respective tuple elements.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reduce method... great way to keep your code clean and compact... Thanks

Comment: :) I fiddled with a reduce version for a bit to put in as well, but got annoyed with it and gave up...  probably because I was trying to be fancy with `numbers.first.map { dropFirst(numbers).reduce($0,$0) { etc }`